# Assign lead to owner based on count

Tags: apex

I am trying to implement the below

Lead  [L1,l2,l3,l4,L5,l6,L7]

OwnerIdMap { ['XXX',3] ['YYYY',2] ['ZZZ',1]}

First 3 Lead should goes to XXX   L1 -XXX, L2 -XXX , L3-XXX

Next 2 Lead should goes to YYY    L4 - YYY, L5 - YYY

Next 1 lead should goes to ZZZ    L6 - ZZZ

Next 3 goes to             XXX    L7 - XXX  and so on.

Struck with Loop. Any idea or help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Common why -ve points. I am trying see the idea or suggestion .

Comment: You're probably getting downvotes because your problem statement isn't very clear, you haven't shown us the code you've tried to write so far, and haven't included the research that you've done so far (to see if this is a feature Salesforce already provides, if someone else has a similar question, or if there's a blog that goes over a similar problem and how to solve it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the list, just use a counter and a wrapper.

## Wrapper

```
class Assignment {
  Id userId;
  Integer counter;
  Assignment(Id userId, Integer counter) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.counter = counter;
  }
}
```

## Basic Algorithm

```
// Initialize
Assignment[] ownerRotation = new Assignment[] {
  new Assignment('XXX',3),
  new Assignment('YYY',2),
  new Assignment('ZZZ',1)
};
Integer currentCounter = 0;
Assignment currentAssignment = ownerRotation[0];
for(Lead record: recordList) {
  record.OwnerId = currentAssignment.userId;
  // Add 1 and compare to limit for current user
  if(++counter == currentAssignment.counter) {
    // Rotate Left operation and assign to current assignment
    ownerRotation.add(currentAssignment = ownerRotation.remove(0));
    counter = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: +100 Awesome @sfdcfox. Thank you so much. it save me lot of loop.